# difficulty in creating linked list

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list

In this programm, when I create a list then it creates list successfully. But when I try to print it the program is just displaying last two values of node. I debug many times and found `(*temp)->next` changes the `start1` and `start2` pointer. I'm unable to solve how `temp` pointer changes value in `start1` and `start2`.

Compiler didn't produce any error or warning.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node {
  int info;
  struct node *next;
} *start1 = NULL, *start2 = NULL;
void create_node(struct node **s1);
void display(struct node **s);

void create_node(struct node **s1)
{
  struct node *ptr = NULL, **temp = s1;
  ptr = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  if (*s1 == NULL)
  {
    *s1 = ptr;
  } else
  {
    while ((*temp)->next != NULL)
      (*temp) = (*temp)->next;
    (*temp)->next = ptr;
  }
  ptr->next = NULL;
  printf("enter the value\n");
  scanf("%d", &(ptr->info));
}
void display(struct node **s)
{
  struct node **temp = s;
  while ((*temp) != NULL)
  {
    printf("%d\t", (*temp)->info);
    (*temp) = (*temp)->next;

  }
}
void main()
{
  int choice = 0;

  while (1){
    clrscr();
    printf("enter your choice\n");
    printf("enter 1 to create_node1\nenter 2 to create node 2 \nenter 3 to display node 1\nenter 4 to display node2\nenter 5 to exit\n");
    printf("\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    switch (choice)
    {
      case 1:
        create_node(&start1);//correct//
        break;
      case 2:
        create_node(&start2);
        break;
      case 3:
        display(&start1);
        getch();
        break;
      case 4:
        display(&start2);
        getch();
        break;
      case 5:
        exit(1);
        break;
      default:
        printf("invalid");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Now is probably a very good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: As you have noticed, `*temp=` modifies the thing `temp` is pointing to, but doesn't change `temp` itself. You probably want `node* temp = *s1` and then `temp = temp->next`.

Comment: And similar in `while ((*temp)->next != NULL)
      (*temp) = (*temp)->next;`-->> `while (*temp != NULL)
      temp = &(*temp)->next;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this
`while ((*temp)->next != NULL) (*temp) = (*temp)->next;`.
This will solve the problem.
Otherwise, the index out of memory is accessed and program crash.